# V4L2 MMAPed memory only bufferable

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, dma, cpu-cache, v4l2

I use an Freescale i.MX6Q board from Phytec. On it runs a yocto/poky based OS using Kernel 3.19.5 with some i.MX IPU and v4l2 and media bus drivers.

My issue is that I want to accelerate an UYVY conversion. Trying out varous techniques (MT, opencv OCL, Neon, ...). A standard integer based conversion using 4 threads takes between 4 to 8 ms of an 640x480 image and 17-25 ms for 1920x1080. But only if I copy the v4l2 buffer to an userspace buffer (time not included above). If I directly convert from the v4l2 buffer to some userspace buffer it takes about 4-8x times as long. Which indicates that this buffer might be uncached (L2). So I dug further and found that the mmaped buffers are allocated by the vb2 dma routines, which use dma_alloc_coherent, which in turn allocates buffers with just the BUFFERABLE flag. From my understanding this means that it does not use the cache right?

The thing is that in this case, as soon as the buffer is dequeued the hardware will never write to that buffer and has finished any previous operations and I do neither, so it makes no sense to not cache the buffer until I queue it back.

Since the you can not force caching from userspace, I thought of using user pointers as buffers. But as far as I can see, although the driver says it supports user pointers, the IPU DMA (IDMAC) does not support scatter and gather, which means that in this case the memory needs to be physically contiguous (and page/cache aligned). Which in turn is a problem since only "drivers" can allocate contiguous buffers. The only driver/api I can recall which does just that is cmem.

So is there some other way to use the cache, of which I have not thought yet or that I overlooked?

Best regards

Comment: You can alter the driver to use cacheable memory and have a VSYNC interrupt which will flush the cache.  You might have better video is you have two buffers and ping-pong them, but this might not be possible without a lot of work.  You need two physically continuous screen buffers and can flip the pointer on VSYNC.  And also [CMA](http://lwn.net/Articles/396657/).

Comment: Hm. Actually, I think I could try to override the mmap (archdata.mmap) function, because it  specifies the pgprot too. The thing is I'm not really sure which one I should use. Furthermore, I am not sure if I need to do additional syncs (invalidate cache) or if they are handled by the vb2/dq functions anyway. A lot of things to check.

Comment: So, what I did so far: I added a copy of the arm_dma_mmap function and added it to ipu/csi video driver and changed it to use the writeback protocol with no allocate (I don't actually write it). After all inits (but before registering the device), I used get_dma_ops to get the currently active ones (or default if none are set), copied it into my global var and pointed the mmap to my new one. So far it looks like it utilizes the cache. Do I have to do another sync? Or are the pages invalidated anyway when dequeuing?

Comment: Ok, definitely need to sync. Not performed by v4l2 in this setup. Looks like either I need to generate a SGT( Scatter-Gather Table) or overwrite the finish function and manually sync to cpu.